# Scrolling up or down from section to section automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I'm trying to implement something in JS like the following.
In a page, every time I scroll up or down, the following div(section) in viewport has to be shown. 
For example, if I scroll down, the page has to move automatically down to the next div(section) and so on. Same for when I scroll up. 
Each div(section) has the viewport height in order to show a full div(section) content every time I scroll up or down. Does it make sense?
Can anyone suggest if it's achievable and how?

The code could be the following:

```
<div class"container">
<div class="section"> content </div> <!-- viewport height -->
<div class="section"> content </div> <!-- viewport height -->
<div class="section"> content </div> <!-- viewport height -->
<div class="section"> content </div> <!-- viewport height -->
<div class="section"> content </div> <!-- viewport height -->
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would recommend against scrolling panes into view on a scroll, they are inconsistent and awkward to use, especially on things such as trackpads or other "mice" with accelerating scrolling.

However, a jQuery solution to scrolling one view port at a time could look like:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop){
    $("html,body").animate({
      scrollTop: $("html,body").css("scrollTop") + $(".section").first().height()
    }, 500);
  } else {
    $("html,body").animate({
      scrollTop: $("html,body").css("scrollTop") - $(".section").first().height()
    }, 500);
  }
  lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
});
```

Comment: I've tried your example but the page remain stuck in position without scrolling

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of scrolling libs out there that solve this, and while you can write the basic functionality easily enough, there tend to be perks such as transition bezier and scrolling threshold built in.

If you're looking to do this by hand, you'll want to compare [element.scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) value with [window.pageYOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageYOffset), and make use of [window.scrollY()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY) to reposition the page.

Generally you'll monitor the [scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) and after x pixels have scrolled in y seconds (make sure to debounce), either scrollY to the next div or back to the current div so you're maintaining edge snap.

A rough idea would be:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
  // set/debounce timer
  // check scroll direction
  // check if pageYOffset is > or < than current section scrollTop
  // scrollY to current, next, or previous section
})
```